# simple oracle stored procedure example for updating two tables in one go

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Could anyone give a simple example of an Oracle stored procedure for updating two tables in a single go.

Comment: see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm

Comment: if single go means atomic(all changes made, otherwise no change) you can do the updates like schurik said and shoot a commit; IF single go means one command, or single unitar treatment of update, see my response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_2_tables
IS
begin
  update t1 set c1 = 1;
  update t2 set c1 = 2;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

I supposed that you update tables a and b with values from c.
This is PL/SQL

```
create or replace procedure update_one_scan as
  cursor c is 
   select a.rowid r1, b.rowid r1, c.value_to_get
   from a join b on (join conditions)
     join c on (join conditions)
   where conditions;
begin
  for r in c
  loop
    update a set col_to_update=r.value_to_get where rowid=r1;
    update b set col_to_update=r.value_to_get where rowid=r2;
  end loop;
end;
```

You have the advantage of single scan of source tables.

**UPDATE:**
You can do it even in oracle SQL, but is more restrictive(you'll see when you try). But this can be faster.

Is a UPDATE SELECT statement:

```
Create or replace Procedure update_select AS
BEGIN
  update
  (select a.col_to_update as c1, b.col_to_update as c2, c.value_to_get v1
         from a join b on (join conditions)
           join c on (join conditions)
         where conditions)
  set 
  c1 = v1, c2 = v2;
END;
```

Comment: ORA-01776: cannot modify more than one base table through a join view

Comment: mmm, probably you are right, I didn't tested that. I used update select statements, but I don't know the restrictions. Thanks.